# How to play Audio Array of Array Javascript?

Tags: javascript, audio

I have an Array of audio

```
[[Audio1.mp3, Audio2.mp3], [Audio3.mp3, Audio4.mp3], ..etc]
```

How to play with js, of I want play the first list Array till end then play next array?

Play audio Array 0 the next array

Comment: Please add the code that you tried to solve this. Simply posting the problem is not enough. Take a look at [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you'd want to classify your raw data into variables (list of playlists of tracks), or just spread them all out into a single array of tracks.

Next, I think you want to choose a player; the [basic HTML one](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio) works but writing a player from scratch might take a bit of time.

If you're comfortable using NPM, which is 'node package manager' you can probably find some really good JS plugins, but that might take a while too.

I think your best bet is to try to make an `<audio>` player and figure out how to auto-advance to the next track in a playlist by searching google or asking chat GPT.

Answer (score 0):

I have made this in next.... my audio is in Array. I am also playing in an audio visualizer

```
 import React, { Component } from "react";
import { AudioContext } from "standardized-audio-context";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isPlaying: false,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.createVisualization();
  }

  createVisualization() {
    const audioList = [
      { audioSrc: "/test.wav", index: 0 },
      { audioSrc: "/test3.wav", index: 1 },
      { audioSrc: "/test2.wav", index: 1 },
      // Add more audio sources as needed
    ];

    var context = new AudioContext();
    let analyser = context.createAnalyser();
    let canvas = this.refs.analyzerCanvas;
    let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    let audio;
    let audioListData = []; // Store decoded audio data for each file
    let source;
    let currentAudioIndex = 0;

    if (audioList.length) {
      // Fetch and decode audio for each file in the list
      Promise.all(
        audioList.map((item) =>
          fetch(item.audioSrc)
            .then((response) => response.arrayBuffer())
            .then((arrayBuffer) => context.decodeAudioData(arrayBuffer))
        )
      )
        .then((decodedAudios) => {
          // Store decoded audio data in the array
          audioListData = decodedAudios;
          console.log("audioListData :>> ", audioListData);
          audioListData.forEach((audioData) => {
            // Set crossOrigin and other settings if needed
            audioData.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
          });

          // Set initial state or perform other setup if needed
          this.setState({ isPlaying: false });
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error("Error fetching/decoding audio:", error);
        });
    }
    // play the decoded audio
    const play = async () => {
      if (!this.state.isPlaying) {
        source = context.createBufferSource();
        source.buffer = audioListData[currentAudioIndex];
        source.connect(context.destination);
        source.connect(analyser);
        analyser.connect(context.destination);
        source.start();
        console.log("playfunction ");

        console.log("source.currentTime; :>> ", source.currentTime);
        if (source.currentTime == 0) {
          console.log("----");
        }
        const test = (source.onended = () => {
          console.log(" onended ");

          if (currentAudioIndex < audioList.length) {
            currentAudioIndex++;
            console.log("currentAudioIndex :>> ", currentAudioIndex);
            source = context.createBufferSource();
            source.buffer = audioListData[currentAudioIndex];
            source.connect(context.destination);
            source.connect(analyser);
            analyser.connect(context.destination);
            source.start();
            source.onended = () => {
              test();
            };
          }
        });
        // context.currentTime = context.currentTime + source.buffer.duration;
        // source.onended = playNext;
        // source.onended = () => {
        //   // Play the next audio when the current one ends
        //   console.log("audioList.length :>> ", audioList.length);
        //   currentAudioIndex = (currentAudioIndex + 1) % audioList.length;
        //   console.log("currentAudioIndex :>> ", currentAudioIndex);
        //   this.play();
        // };

        this.setState({ isPlaying: true });
        renderFrame();
        // currentAudioIndex = (currentAudioIndex + 1) % audioList.length;
      } else {
        source.stop();
        context.close().then(() => {
          this.setState({ isPlaying: false });
          this.createVisualization(); // Re-initialize for potential re-use
        });
      }
    };

    const renderFrame = () => {
      let freqData = new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);
      requestAnimationFrame(renderFrame);
      analyser.getByteFrequencyData(freqData);
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

      ctx.fillStyle = "#00579b";

      let bars = 1500;
      for (var i = 0; i < bars; i++) {
        let bar_x = i * 2;
        let bar_width = 1;
        let bar_height = -(freqData[i] / 4); // Adjust this line to flip the pitch upside down
        ctx.fillRect(bar_x, canvas.height / 2, bar_width, bar_height);

        // Draw the same graph on the top side (upside-down)
        ctx.fillRect(bar_x, canvas.height / 2, bar_width, -bar_height);
      }
    };

    this.play = play;
    this.stop = stop;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App relative">
        <div id="mp3_player" className="pb-card ">
          <div className=" border-dotted border-b-2 border-primary w-full mt-container pt-container mb-[-76px] md:mb-[-176px] lg:mb-[-220px]  "></div>
          <canvas
            ref="analyzerCanvas"
            id="analyzer"
            className=" min-w-max md:w-[700px] lg:w-[878px]  -z-20 mx-auto   "
          />
          <button
            className="btn-primary p-4 rounded-full h-10 w-10 md:h-20 md:w-20 absolute top-0 sm:top-5  lg:top-12 left-[50%] "
            onClick={this.play}
          >
            <svg
              xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
              className=" mx-auto  w-2 md:w-5"
              viewBox="0 0 22 25"
              fill="none"
            >
              <path
                d="M20.7227 10.4818L3.53516 0.3207C2.13867 -0.504495 0 0.296286 0 2.3373V22.6547C0 24.4857 1.9873 25.5893 3.53516 24.6713L20.7227 14.515C22.2559 13.6117 22.2607 11.3852 20.7227 10.4818Z"
                fill="white"
              />
            </svg>
            <svg
              xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
              className="mx-auto  hidden"
              viewBox="0 0 23 23"
              fill="none"
            >
              <path
                d="M7.7312 22.3291H3.0437C1.74976 22.3291 0.699951 21.2793 0.699951 19.9854V2.79785C0.699951 1.50391 1.74976 0.454102 3.0437 0.454102H7.7312C9.02515 0.454102 10.075 1.50391 10.075 2.79785V19.9854C10.075 21.2793 9.02515 22.3291 7.7312 22.3291ZM22.575 19.9854V2.79785C22.575 1.50391 21.5251 0.454102 20.2312 0.454102H15.5437C14.2498 0.454102 13.2 1.50391 13.2 2.79785V19.9854C13.2 21.2793 14.2498 22.3291 15.5437 22.3291H20.2312C21.5251 22.3291 22.575 21.2793 22.575 19.9854Z"
                fill="white"
              />
            </svg>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```